# How to get equally scaled axes with Plots in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I have created a heatmap plot using in Julia by using the `Plotly` with the `Plots` package. I generate the heatmap with the following command `heatmap(10^9 .* (height + deformation))`. Then, I get a plot that looks like this
[image: heatmap]

The length of the x-axis and y-axis both range from 0 to 256, but nonetheless they do not have the same scale as seen from the rectangular shape of the heatmap. How can I make the scale of the x-axis and y-axis equal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `aspect_ratio` attribute with `:equal` option.

```
heatmap(10^9 .* (height + deformation), aspect_ratio=:equal)
```

should give you equally scaled x and y axes. If you give a number instead of `:equal`, plot area is resized so that 1 y-unit is the same size as `aspect_ratio` x-units.

You can see other attributes to use with `Plots.jl` in [the relevant section](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/) of `Plots.jl` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to work on my setup.
Plots v1.39.0
PlotlyJS v0.18.12

```
using Plots
plotly()  
xs = [1,2,3, 4]  
ys = [10,20,30, 40]  
scatter(xs, ys, aspect_ratio=1)
```

I can pass any number as well as `:equal` to the aspect_ratio argument without any affect on the plot..

The only thing that seems to work for my setup is manually setting the plot size with  `plotly(size=(x_size,y_size))` and manually setting xlim and ylim,  but that sucks a little.

Comment: update, for a while during testing using aspect_ratio=1 worked, and now it stopped working again...